# PHP prepared statement bind multiples variables to one array

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm trying to bind my variables into one array.  Currently, I have them in their own array.  What might I need to do to bind them into one array?

```
$catSelect = $db->prepare("SELECT... WHERE jos_categories.alias = ?");
$catSelect->bind_param('s', $category);
$catSelect->execute();
$catSelect->bind_result($contentAlias, $contentCatID, $contentTitle, $contentID);

$contentAliasArray = array();
$contentCatIDArray = array();
$contentTitleArray = array();
$contentIDArrray   = array();

while ($catSelect->fetch()) {
    $contentAliasArray[]=$contentAlias;
    $contentCatIDArray[] = $contentCatID;
    $contentTitleArray[] = $contentTitle;
    $contentIDArrray[] = $contentID;
}

$catSelect->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT... WHERE jos_categories.alias = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $category);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$array = $res->fetch_all();
```

another way is to swap mysqli for PDO

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT... WHERE jos_categories.alias = ?");
$stmt->execute([$category]);
$array = $res->fetchAll();
```